# how can i display all the json data in the html page using the given php code

Tags: php, html, json

when i type in a movie name in the search field i want to display all the movies that is the json file but with this code i can only get one of the movies can you please help me with this.

```
<?php

            if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {

                $txtresult = $_POST['search'];

                function    getImdbRecord($title, $ApiKey)
                    {
                        $path = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=$title&apikey=$ApiKey";
                        $json = file_get_contents($path);
                        return json_decode($json, TRUE);

                    }
                $data = getImdbRecord($txtresult, "f3d054e8");  


                 echo "<div class = 'info-box'><img src =".$data['Poster']."</img><h3> Name :".$data['Title']."</h3><h3> Year : ".$data['Year']."</h3><h3> Duration : ".$data['Runtime'],"</h3></div>";



    }

        ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

you have need to use foreach loop to get all the search result.

like.

```
$data = getImdbRecord($txtresult, "f3d054e8");  
foreach($data['Search'] as $value){
    echo "<div class = 'info-box'><img src =".$value['Poster']."</img><h3> Name :".$value['Title']."</h3><h3> Year : ".$value['Year']."</h3><h3> Duration : ".$value['Runtime'],"</h3></div>";
}
```

Complete code will be.

```
 <?php
 //add function out side the if condition
function getImdbRecord($title, $ApiKey){
                $path = "http://www.omdbapi.com/?s=$title&apikey=$ApiKey";
                $json = file_get_contents($path);
                return json_decode($json, TRUE);

}


if (isset($_POST['submit-search'])) {
   $txtresult = $_POST['search'];
   $data = getImdbRecord($txtresult, "f3d054e8");  
   //use loop to get all the seacrh result.
    foreach($data['Search'] as $value){
        echo "<div class = 'info-box'><img src =".$value['Poster']."</img><h3> Name :".$value['Title']."</h3><h3> Year : ".$value['Year']."</h3><h3> Duration : ".$value['Runtime'],"</h3></div>";
    }
}
?>
```